# GremlinServerError: 499

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython, graph-notebook

I am running a Neptune Server on AWS and making gremlin queries to the db ipython cell magic in an jupyter notebook. I've got a number of traversals running and I am getting an error that is coming from `aiogoblin` in their `resultset.py` file: `GremlinServerError: 499: {"requestId":"5bb1e6ea-49ec-4a1d-9364-2b1bf717df9c","code":"InvalidParameterException","detailedMessage":"The [eval] message contains 66 bindings which is more than is allowed by the server 64 configuration"}`

How can I make continued queries against the server without this error message popping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there was a known issue with the client/magic you are using and I don't think it has been updated in four years or so. I vaguely remember you could work around it by doing something like `%reset` in the cell but I really think you would be better off using a different client that is regularly updated and supported.

You could instead use the Apache TinkerPop Gremlin Python client (pip install gremlinpython) or try the new Amazon Neptune Workbench which offers a `%%gremlin` cell magic.

If you use the Gremlin Python client in a Jupyter notebook you can still issue queries in much the same way, you would just need to establish a connection to the server in a cell before issuing Python based queries. There is a blog post that may be of interest located here [1] and a stand alone Python example you could use to create a cell containing the imports and setup steps can be found here [2] and here [3]. In the sample you would replace `localhost` with the DNS name of your Neptune endpoint.

If you decide to try the new Neptune Workbench you can create one from the AWS Neptune Console web page.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/let-me-graph-that-for-you-part-1-air-routes/
[2] https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/basic-client.py
[3] https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/glv-client.py

Comment: Thank you @Kelvin Lawrence. Very helpful.

Comment: My pleasure.  Happy graphing :-)

Comment: I created a fresh environment with jupyter, gremlin python and now I am getting `RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running` which is being propagated by tornado. Did something change in `gremlinpython`  in the past few weeks? I would use the `%%gremlin` magic but I want to do visualizations in the notebook

Comment: I am using Gremlin Python 3.4.3 and Tornado 4.5.1 with no issues in a notebook. What versions do you have installed?

Comment: I was using python3.6. But I tried with python3.5 since Python 3.4 is not available in conda. I installed version 4.5.1 tornado and also tried 3.4.5 and 3.4.4 for gremlinpython. With this installation I get `HTTP 599: Timeout while connecting`.

Comment: I was referring to My GremlinPython version being 3.4.3 not Python itself. Can you reach the /status endpoint using curl from a %%bash cell in the notebook just to make sure that there is not an issue reaching Neptune?

Comment: All good. Thank you Kelvin. Problem solved. I had forgotten that I needed to be in the  same VPC as the instance...